# condition for an MVC checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox in an MVC project called:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ShowAll", true)
```

and then in my js I want to check if the checkbox is checked or not.

Something like

```
 function checkboxAll(item)
{ 
  if ((showAll).isChecked)
 {
   //do stuff
```

whats the best way? I cant seem to get the syntax right

Thanks
     }
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what your MVC creates, but select the element either by ID or class, and then simply use the checked property:  `document.getElementById("ShowAll").checked`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Or using jquery - `var isChecked = $('#ShowAll').is(':checked');`

Answer (score 1):

When using `@Html.Checkbox` the first parameter is the html attribute "name" that will be applied when the checkbox is created.

If you retrieve a DOM element from a html attribute you can use the following jquery:

```
var isChecked = $("[Name='ShowAll']").val()
```

P.S. I can't guarantee this is correct and will edit comment later if it is.

Answer (score 0):

So if you write `@Html.CheckBox("ShowAll", true)` this renders a checkbox with below properties.

```
<input checked="checked" 
        id="ShowAll" 
        name="ShowAll" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="true" />
```

Also it generates a hidden input like this:

```
<input name="CheckBox" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

Now you know how to get a field by name or id in jquery.

access value by

```
$("input[name='ShowAll']").val()
```

or is checked

```
 $("input[name='ShowAll']").is(':checked')
```

or by pure js `var chkbox = document.getElementsByName("ShowAll");`

See the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox(v=vs.118).aspx) for complete overloads.

Comment: You're combining vanilla JS and JQuery, it should be `.val()` not `.value`, and `.is(':checked')` not `.checked` for the JQuery options.